# Building ffmpeg-kit for Android fails with arm-linux-androideabi-strip not found

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg-kit for Android with "android.sh". The build.log ends with:

```
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from <built-in>:370:
<command line>:13:9: warning: '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __ANDROID_API__ 24
        ^
<built-in>:363:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __ANDROID_API__ __ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION__
        ^
6 warnings generated.
GEN     libavdevice/libavdevice.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libavfilter/libavfilter.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libavformat/libavformat.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libavcodec/libavcodec.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libswresample/libswresample.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libswscale/libswscale.pc
1 warning generated.
GEN     libavutil/libavutil.pc
```

...

```
INSTALL doc/examples/scaling_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/README
INSTALL doc/examples/Makefile
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.so
STRIP   install-libavdevice-shared
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-androideabi-strip: not found
make: *** [ffbuild/library.mak:104: install-libavdevice-shared] Error 127
```

I have no idea what goes wrong. I have cloned the github repository again, with the same result.